# IOS - Swift 4.0 - Basic access authentication with Alamofire -

Tags: ios, swift, post, alamofire, basic-authentication

I'm doing an app in Swift 4 i when I get to the point where I need to make a POST call, like "Basic access authentication" with a header and a body with parameters, it does not work for me.

Basically I want to simulate this call, to return a 200, but it's giving me back:

> "responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character
>   0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.})) "

The API url is:

https://gist.github.com/juaniiton1/3a3e422ed99de22f3f3686bb3b7788d7

and the section is "Store a new trade in the authed user portfolio".

Here I pass the code that simulates the request "Store a new trade in the authoved user portfolio" with the help of Alamofire (4.7.3).

The steps I follow are the following:

- What I do is, code the data of "username" and "password" that you
  give me in base64.
- Then I format the date of type Stirng to type Date (type ISO).
- After I created a dictionary for the data
- And finally I created the request, putting together all of the above.
- In addition in the Xcode I have the TransportSecurity to make the
  request "https"

Here I leave the code:

import Foundation
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //URL
    let url = URL(string: "https://test.cryptojet.io/coins/portfolio")!

    // credentials encoded in base64
    let username = "richard@rich.com"
    let password = "secret"
    let loginData = String(format: "%@:%@", username, password).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    let base64LoginData = loginData.base64EncodedString()
    let headers = ["Authorization" : "Basic \(base64LoginData)",
                   "Content-Type": "application/json"]

    //Prepare date - Data UTC to ISO
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ"
    let dataSting = "2016-06-05T16:56:57.019+01:00"
    let dateISO = dateFormatter.date(from: dataSting)

    //Prepare paramsBody -> tot Data
    let paramsBody: [String: Any] = ["coin_id": 2,
                                     "amount": -2.2183,
                                     "price_usd": 675.982,
                                     "traded_at": dateISO!]

    //Request
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post,parameters: paramsBody, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            guard let json = response.result.value as? [String: Any],
                let data = json["trade"] as? [String: Any] else {
                    return
            }
            print(data)
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }

}
```

Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong with this POST authentication call with the server?

Comment: Are you trying to use digest protocol? if this is the issue you need to use alamo in a different way

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make request to your url and seems response from your request is not JSON:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
        <style>            body { background-color: #F9F9F9; color: #222; font: 14px/1.4 Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding-bottom: 45px; }

            a { cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; }
            a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
...
```

Comment: Yeah, it seems that the API does not work with POST type, with the GET type it does return JSON response.

Comment: Yes, the API does work in POST.

I know because the one who gave me the test says: "I see where the error is but you will understand that if I tell you the solution, the test would be grace since it is a problem of the code and not of the backend. .. "

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying digest you will need this method :

```
    credential = URLCredential(user: UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userName") ?? "admin", password: UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "password") ?? "admin", persistence: .none)

    let sessionMananager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
    _ = sessionMananager.request(url)
        .authenticate(usingCredential: credential!)
        .responseJSON { response in
 }
```